# In or On Microsoft Excel's Table/Cells/Column

Tags: prepositions, in-on, prepositional-objects

I have a rather odd question here. I am delivering a presentation to a wide audience of Excel users.

How do you go about using prepositions when it comes down to Microsoft Excel's Worksheet, Workbook, Table, Chart, Columns, Cells, Formula Bar, and Rows? Would you use **In** a table or **on** a table/cell?

Comment: Thank you for that link. However, It's still hard to say. I've heard people using both quite frequently when referring to objects/values in Excel. I've heard people say In cell A1. But, I've also heard people say on Cell A1

Comment: Related question, [Is it “described in” or “described on”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158756/is-it-described-in-or-described-on/).

Comment: As the answer to the linked question indicates, *in* means inside and there is no reason not to use *on*. Please see the [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+worksheet%2Con+the+worksheet&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20worksheet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20worksheet%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: My pleasure. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer may be different between British English and American English. In the U.S., we tend to say and write "in a cell, table, spreadsheet," while our British counterparts may prefer to use "on." It's an old adage but still applies, "Write for your reader." Choose which you use based on your likely audience.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I feel more comfortable saying "on" in most cases, however when thinking from a logical perspective, referring to a value that sit "in" a table on Excel sounds more appropriate